# Solve equations with symbolic input MatLab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a coupled equation.
I have function V depending on changing variable tk(n) and function UP. This is my input for the solving the equation for the UP.

Here is my code:

```
OMG=zeros(kPoints,1);
for nn1=1:kPoints
    OMG(nn1)=sqrt(tk(nn1))*(tanh((-sqrt(betaV)*betaU*sqrt(tk(nn1))+sqrt(betaV)*sqrt(tk(nn1)*tk(nn1*tk(nn1)))./CHI*CHI))./sqrt(betaV)   ;
end;

V=zeros(kPoints,1);
% UP=zeros(kPoints,1);
syms UP;
for nn1=1:kPoints-1
    V(nn1)=(CHI*UP)./(tk(nn1)-betaV*OMG(nn1));
    S=solve(UP==-CHI*sum(V((nn1)))+1i*betaU*UP,UP);
end;
```

MatLab gives an error saying: `DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into
a double array.`
I'll appreciate any detailed help beforehand.
Thank you

Comment: Which line gives that error?

Comment: The third line of your code (inside the FOR loop) seems to be missing a parenthesis someplace.

Comment: It sounds like whatever is giving you the error is not a symbolic value, but a symbolic equation. `double(sym('exp(x)'))` give the same error because there is no way for it to be converted to a numeric value unless `x` is been assigned a numeric value. This can be done via the `subs` function.